# solution of $y' = \exp \left(-\frac yx\right) + \frac yx$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could you help me to solve equation 
$$y' = \exp \left(-\frac yx\right) + \frac yx;\quad y(e) = 0$$

I know how to solve 1st order linear de like $y' = \exp \bigl(-\frac 1x\bigr) + \frac yx$ but here I have the dependent variable in the part that usually (in my practice) was free of it.

Comment: Try the change of function $z = \frac{y}{x}$. Then $z' = \frac{y'}{x} - \frac{y}{x^2}$ so that $y' = xz' + z$. Your ODE then becomes $$xz' + z = \exp(-z)+z.$$ Can you see how to solve this?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27=exp%28-y/x%29%2b%28y/x%29,%20y%28e%29=0 you can find a step by step solution.

Answer (score 8):

This can be written in the form $y'=F(\frac{y}{x})$, so this is a homogeneous ODE.

Let $z=\frac{y}{x}$, so that we obtain $y' = e^{-z} + z$.

Observe that $z=\frac{y}{x} \implies y=zx \implies y'=z'x+z$ by the product rule.

Therefore,

$$ \begin{align}
y' &= e^{-z} + z \\
z'x+z &=e^{-z}+z \\
z'x &=e^{-z} \\
z'&= \frac{e^{-z}}{x} \\
\frac{dz}{dx} &= \frac{e^{-z}}{x} \\
e^z dz &= \frac{dx}{x} \\
\int e^z dz &= \int \frac{dx}{x} \\
e^z &=\ln|x| + C \\
z &= \ln\left(\ln|x| + C \right). \\
\end{align} $$

Recall, form above, that $y=zx$. So the general solution is $y=x\ln(\ln|x|+C)$. Now we must solve for $C$ using the initial condition,

$$ \begin{align}
y(e) &= 0\\
e \ln(\ln|e|+C) &= 0\\
e \ln(1 + C) &= 0\\
\ln(1+C) &= 0\\
1+C &= e^0\\
1+C &= 1\\
C &= 0 \\
\end{align} $$

So the solution is,

> $$y=x\ln \left(\ln|x| \right).$$

$ \ $

You may find these resources helpful:

1. [Paul's Online Notes - Substitutions](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Substitutions.aspx)
2. [PatrickJMT Video Examples](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEtEAYi2cIA&list=ECD4B0062CA82D73FB)